# How do you force the Linux kernel to reclaim unused process memory in C#?

Tags: c#, linux, garbage-collection, heap-memory, libc

This code creates 2 GiB of objects, then garbage collects them.  Afterwards, the process is still using 2 GiB+ of memory.  In Windows, I was able to force Windows to reclaim the memory by calling `SetProcessWorkingSetSize()` from `kernel32.dll` (see code below).  Result:

[image]

With Linux (`Ubuntu 20.04`), the code calls `madvise` with `MADV_DONTNEED`, and also `madvise` with `MADV_PAGEOUT` from `libc`, however both return `-1` with an error code of `0`.  It also calls `malloc_trim(0)`, which succeeds.  However, despite these approaches, the process working set is still 2 GiB+:

[image]

How can I achieve the same outcome with Linux, as I achieved with Windows?  If it's not possible, what's the best strategy?  Thank you!

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GCtest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            PrintMemoryUsage();

            UseLotsOfMemory();

            MemoryUtility.ForceGcAndSetProcessWorkingSet();

            PrintMemoryUsage();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void UseLotsOfMemory()
        {
            const int objectSize = 1024*1024*100; // 100 MiB
            const int numberOfObjectsToCreate = 20;
            var datas = new List<byte[]>();
            var rng = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToCreate; i++)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[objectSize];
                rng.NextBytes(data);
                datas.Add(data);
                PrintMemoryUsage();
            }
        }

        private static long GetMemoryUsage()
        {
            var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            return process.WorkingSet64;
        }

        private static void PrintMemoryUsage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Process working set: {GetMemoryUsage():n0} bytes");
            Console.WriteLine($"GC total memory    : {GC.GetTotalMemory(false):n0} bytes");
        }
    }

    public static class MemoryUtility
    {
        public static void ForceGcAndSetProcessWorkingSet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Forcing blocking GC collection and compacting of gen2 LOH and updating OS process working set size...");
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
            GC.Collect(generation: 2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, blocking: true, compacting: true);

            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                WindowsMemoryUtility.ReleaseUnusedProcessWorkingSetMemory();
            }
            else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            {
                LinuxMemoryUtility.ReleaseUnusedProcessWorkingSetMemoryWithMallocTrim();
                LinuxMemoryUtility.ReleaseUnusedProcessWorkingSetMemoryWithMadvise_MADV_DONTNEED();
                LinuxMemoryUtility.ReleaseUnusedProcessWorkingSetMemoryWithMadvise_MADV_PAGEOUT();
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Completed GC and setting process working set in {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} ms");
        }

        public class LinuxMemoryUtility
        {
            [DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
            private static extern int madvise(IntPtr addr, UIntPtr length, int advice);

            // https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1a4e58cce84ee88129d5d49c064bd2852b481357/arch/alpha/include/uapi/asm/mman.h
            private const int MADV_DONTNEED = 6;
            private const int MADV_PAGEOUT = 21;

            /// <summary>
            /// https://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise
            /// </summary>
            public static void ReleaseUnusedProcessWorkingSetMemoryWithMadvise_MADV_DONTNEED()
            {
                // https://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise

                try
                {
                    var startMemoryAddress = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress;
                    var memoryLength = new UIntPtr((ulong)Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Calling madvise with start: {startMemoryAddress} and length: {memoryLength}");

                    int result = madvise(startMemoryAddress, memoryLength, MADV_DONTNEED);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");

                    // On success madvise() returns zero. On error, it returns -1 and errno is set appropriately.
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"madvise errno: {Marshal.GetLastSystemError()}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// https://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise
            /// </summary>
            public static void ReleaseUnusedProcessWorkingSetMemoryWithMadvise_MADV_PAGEOUT()
            {
                
                try
                {
                    var startMemoryAddress = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress;
                    var memoryLength = new UIntPtr((ulong)Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Calling madvise with start: {startMemoryAddress} and length: {memoryLength}");

                    int result = madvise(startMemoryAddress, memoryLength, MADV_PAGEOUT);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");

                    // On success madvise() returns zero. On error, it returns -1 and errno is set appropriately.
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"madvise errno: {Marshal.GetLastSystemError()}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc);
                }
            }

            [DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
            private static extern int malloc_trim(uint pad);

            public static void ReleaseUnusedProcessWorkingSetMemoryWithMallocTrim()
            {
                // https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Calling malloc_trim(0)");
                    int result = malloc_trim(0);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");

                    // The malloc_trim() function returns 1 if memory was actually
                    // released back to the system, or 0 if it was not possible to
                    // release any memory.
                    if (result != 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"malloc_trim errno: {Marshal.GetLastSystemError()}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc);
                }
            }
        }

        public class WindowsMemoryUtility
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr proc, int minSize, int maxSize);

            public static void ReleaseUnusedProcessWorkingSetMemory()
            {
                SetProcessWorkingSetSize(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```